# Can I ask the same question on Stack Overflow, Webmasters and Programmers to get fast and diverse answers?

Tags: discussion, cross-posting

If any question can be asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) and [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), can I ask in all to get quick and different views?

Comment: Why negative vote? I just asked a question. Is my question not clear? or not related to meta?

Comment: On Meta, [voting is used to express agreement or disagreement.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences)

Comment: Negative votes here often indicate disapproval of the practice discussed, not necessarily a bad question. (PS: I did not downvote this question, although I disapprove of cross-posting.)

Comment: @Anna: Whoa, when did that get added to the FAQ? I had no idea that I could just link to an explanation each time this question gets asked in the comments.

Comment: @CodyGray: and don't forget you can just slap faq#vote-differences inbetween two square brackets [].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cross-posting is *strongly* discouraged: while you may think it's on-topic without modification on several different Stack Exchange sites, each site has its own culture and audience, and at the very least you should be tailoring your question to meet that.

To this point, there are *very few* questions that are on-topic on *both* Stack Overflow and Programmers.SE. Their scopes are purposely designed to be exclusive: Stack Overflow for concrete implementation questions and Programmers.SE for conceptual, whiteboard-y questions. And Webmasters.SE isn't even for questions targeted towards programmers at all.

So it's best not to even try to cross-post; instead, pick the site with the *best* fit. If you misjudge, the community can sort it out by migrating it to the correct site.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to [what Mark said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98383/if-any-question-can-be-asked-on-stackoveflow-webmasters-and-programmers-can-i-a/98384#98384), many users (especially across the sites you mention) participate on more than one site, so your question would have a high chance of being migrated to one location and its various incarnations merged together anyway.

You're generally better off picking the right/best place for your question and sticking with that.

Comment: The *communities* would probably be better off if you stuck to one place. I'm not at all sure the OP would be better off.

Comment: @ire_and_curses In terms of using Stack Exchange correctly and not getting weird migrations or uninformed answers, the OP would be better off as well.